# What is an appropriate command at the Windows Batch command in Jenkins, to trigger MATLAB?

Tags: windows, matlab, batch-file, jenkins

I tried following the steps from [this blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2015/01/20/the-other-kind-of-continuous-integration/).

As my machine works on Windows 10, I used the "*Execute Windows batch command*", instead of the "*Execute shell*" command. The command which I wrote down was the following:

```
C:\<a long path here>\matlab.exe" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('C:\<a long path here>\mfile.m');
```

in an attempt to open a MATLAB file. This works when I do it on the command line of my computer. After saving the job in jenkins, with this build, the build is successful but I get the following result:

[image]

Theoretically, the result on the console output should be the something similar to the following, as it is shown on the blog which I mentioned previously(bearing in mind that I have done something different in my attempt to open an existing script):

[image]

One thing that I suspect is that this happens because the directory in which the file that I am trying to open is saved, is different from the directory in which MATLAB is installed. When I tried saving a MATLAB file in the directory in which MATLAB is installed, my computer would not let me to do it. How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure that the command you wrote started with "C:\\matlab.exe"? Because i) _nobody_ installs MATLAB directly into C: ii) your error message says that Jenkins is looking for matlab.exe in a different path, where it also can't find it. What _exactly_ was your command?

Comment: @SamRoberts Hi, and thanks once again for your comments. My command was the following: C:\Users\Zachos>"C:Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin\matlab.exe" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('C:\Users\Zachos\Documents\MATLAB\scripttry.m');"  , where scripttry is an existing matlab script saved in the specified direcotry.

Comment: A couple of initial thoughts: i) make sure to put C:\Program Files, with the \ ii) Did you type it into Jenkins or cut and paste? I've had problems before where Jenkins replaced straight quotes with curly quotes during a paste operation, and I got the same issue. Try checking those things.

Comment: PS the `run` command is redundant, you should just be able to call `-r "scripttry; exit;"` with the same effect.

Comment: Will try those, thanks again!